# Are senior loans appropriate to retail investors ?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, fixed-income

I understand senior loans to be a class of unsecured debt instrument which a company has to prioritise payment of over other unsecured debt in the case of failure.

In principle, this appears to make senior loans an attractive high-risk fixed interest investment option. Investment in senior loans is possible through various ETF (e.g. [BKLN](http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0000SKPK)).

What risks are associated with investment in senior loans compared to long-term corporate bonds ? Are there any good reasons why retail investors do not typically invest in senior loans ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [very nice investopedia article](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/101415/diversifying-senior-loans-worth-risk.asp) from a couple of years ago which analyses pretty much this very question.  A few choice quotes:

> You might be thinking that a default shouldn’t be much of a concern
>   since the loan is secured. However, there is no guarantee that you
>   will be paid in full. According to Credit Suisse, the recovery rate
>   for senior loans since 1995 has been 70%. This is significantly higher
>   than the recovery rate for junk bonds of 46% over the same time frame,
>   but 70% is still not 100%.

...

> There appear to be a few interesting opportunities, but at what risk?
>   Fixed income is supposed to be a stable part of an investment
>   portfolio. The focus should be on capital preservation while earning a
>   low yet safe return. It’s not a part of the portfolio where credit
>   risk should come into play.

(that previous paragraph in particular would seem to explain why these things aren't so interesting for "ordinary" retail investors)

...

> The risk/reward for senior loans over the next 1-3 years isn't
>   favorable. When seeking fixed income, it’s highly recommended that you
>   look at investment-grade corporate bonds, high-quality municipal
>   bonds, Treasuries and CDs before considering them. Investing in senior
>   loans is like investing in a stock with limited upside potential and
>   significant downside risk.

There's some analysis of BLKN specifically in the middle of it which includes (bear in mind this was written 2015):

> The bad news is that BKLN has depreciated 4.53% over the past 12
>   months. Taking a look at a bigger picture, it has slid 7.73% since its
>   inception on March 3, 2011. That being the case, how do you expect it
>   to perform if conditions worsen?